# How to build arch/machine dependent code with autotools

Tags: c, architecture, build, autotools

I am getting started with autotools and I am working on a C project that requires different build paths for different architectures (i386 and x86_64).

So far my directory structure is

```
/maindir
        /arch
             /i386/code.S
             /x86_64/code.S
        /src/main.c
        /include/config.h
                /other_header.h
```

I am very new with autotools and I don't really understand them well, I followed a couple of tutorials however I couldn't find a way to specify a different directory based on the current CPU's architecture.

Can somebody provide me a short example of makefile.am and configure.ac files to make this happen? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you have to call `AC_CANONICAL_HOST` somewhere in your `configure.ac`. It will set the variable `host_cpu`, which you then can query.

Here is an excerpt from an example `configure.ac`:

```
...

AC_CANONICAL_HOST

AS_CASE([$host_cpu],
  [i?86], [ARCHDIR=arch/i386],
  [x86_64], [ARCHDIR=arch/x86_64],
  [AC_MSG_ERROR("No assembler code for CPU $host_cpu")]
)
AC_SUBST([ARCHDIR])

...
```

(Note that `i?86` is used to match `i586`, `i686` etc.) With this, you can use `$(ARCHDIR)` in your `Makefile.am`.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I had found a half-assed solution with AC_SUBST and uname -m but this is way more portable, thank you!

Comment: Just a small update, I realized you actually need to use @ARCHDIR@ in the Makefile.am and not $(ARCHDIR).